# I'm searching for some books with guidance into mathematical study.

Tags: big-list, learning

Yesterday, I've found [this](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/files/imported/prospective-students/undergraduate/introduction/pdf/introbook.pdf). It's a PDF file with this purpose, from Oxford.

Some weeks ago I've also found two books tha seems to fill this purpose:

- [Prelude to Mathematics;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486244016)
- [I Want to Be a Mathematician.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387960783)

I'm not searching for something specific as I still have no idea on what I want to do with mathematics, then you can suggest books with guidance for any level of mathematical study.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the book by Halmos is interesting, but will not tell you a great deal about mathematics. You may like Polya's little book *How to Prove it*.

Comment: Community Wiki?

Comment: I can't find the community Wiki.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can this book help me to find a way on mathematics? I thought It could only suggest some heuristics for math problem solving.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: So you are looking for information of what the study of mathematics would entail? At what stage are you now?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I've been instructed to learn calculus by now. I'm learning mostly with two books: What is Mathematics? and Mathematics for the Nonmathematician. I'm also reading some other books, such as Stewart's Calculus - I'm halted at this book by now because in the beginning, he suggests the study of trigonometrical functions but only supperficially - then I decided to get some book on trigonometry and then return back to the calculus book. Teh trigonometrical functions are easy, but I want a deeped understanding.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think _How to prove it_ is by Daniel Velleman and _How to solve it_ is by Polya. And it will be great if the OP would let us know: 1. His background(like what you already know) 2. Where s/he is headed(mathematician? Physicist? ...) 3. Do you guidance _into_ the field of mathematics or _material_ so that you can get down to business. THx

Comment: Thanks, it is *How to Solve it* that I recommend.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read *[Letters to a Young Mathematician](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465082327)* by Ian Stwart. It describes informally what mathematics is and what mathematicians do. When you have done some college level mathematics already and wish to survey the branches of mathematics, you may take a look at *[The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691118809)* edited by Fields medallist Timothy Gowers.

Comment: You decided to read my questions! =)

Comment: I've looked the Princeton Companion, but it's a little hard now. But I know it's a great resource for surveying.

Comment: My recommendation, as well.